# Using PrintWriter on an object in a class

Tags: java

I have a class that test for the amount of money put into a vending machine. The initial values are stored in a txt file. I'm trying to use a printWriter to take the user input and store it in the txt file. For example, the starting amount of dimes is 5. The user puts in 2 dimes and the new amount in the text file is 7.

This is all Money.txt has in it:

```
5 //nickels
5 //dimes
5 //quarters
0 //halfdollars
```

This is my money class:
public class Money

```
{
    private int nickels;
    private int quarters;
    private int dimes;
    private int halfs;


    public void increNickels() {
        nickels ++;
    }

    public int getNickels(){
        return nickels;
    }

    public void increQuarters(){
        quarters ++;
    }

    public int getQuarters(){
        return quarters;
    }

    public void increDimes(){
        dimes ++;
    }

    public int getDimes(){
        return dimes;
    }

    public void increHalfs(){
        halfs ++;
    }

    public int getHalfs(){
        return halfs;
    }
}
```

This is my vending class:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     *
     * @author Mira and Ty
     */
    public class VendingClass {

            Money moneyObj;
            public Item [] itemList;
            public Money [] moneyList;
            Integer noCode = null;

            int itemChoiceNum;

        public VendingClass(){

            moneyObj = new Money();
            itemList = new Item [4];
            moneyList = new Money [4];
        }
        public void setItemList() throws IOException {

        String welcome = "Welcome to the \n \t\tPolemon Distribution Center \n \t\t\tPlease note that if there is not enough \nmoney in "
                    + "machine correct change \nwill not be given."; // creates welcome message

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, welcome);
            int itemQuantity; //variable that will display item code

            String items; //creates the String variable items which elements from itemNames array will be stored into
            int itemCost; //creates the integer variable itemCost whic elements from itemCosts array will be stored into

            File itemFile = new File("items.txt");
            Scanner itemScan = new Scanner(itemFile);

            int code = -1;
            for(int x = 0; x < itemList.length; x++){      //for loop addes the elements of each array and itemCode to itemList object
                items = itemScan.nextLine();
                itemCost = itemScan.nextInt();
                itemQuantity = itemScan.nextInt();
                itemScan.nextLine();
                code++;
                itemList[x] = new Item(code, items, itemCost, itemQuantity);
            }
            itemScan.close();
        }

    public void setMoney() throws IOException {

            File moneyFile = new File("Money.txt");
            Scanner moneyScan = new Scanner(moneyFile);

             for(int x = 0; x < moneyList.length; x++){
                int nickels = moneyScan.nextInt();
                int dimes = moneyScan.nextInt();
                int quarters = moneyScan.nextInt();
                int halfs = moneyScan.nextInt();
            }

            moneyScan.close();
    }



        public void displayVend(){

            String itemChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, itemList);
                itemChoiceNum = Integer.parseInt(itemChoice);

            if(itemChoice == null){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for your service. Goodbye!");
            }

                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You've caught a " + itemList[itemChoiceNum].getItem());


          }

        public void insertMoney() throws IOException{

            int moneyNeeded = itemList[itemChoiceNum].getCost();//price of item will be decremented

            while(moneyNeeded > 0){ //while loop testing the amount of money added to vending machine
            String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Pokemon: " + itemList[itemChoiceNum].getItem() + "\n You owe" + moneyNeeded + "\nEnter 50, 25, 10, or 5");

PrintWriter mw = new PrintWriter("Money.txt");            
int userMoney = Integer.parseInt(message);
            moneyNeeded = moneyNeeded - userMoney;

            if(userMoney == 5){
                mw.moneyObj.increNickels();
            }

            if(userMoney == 10){
                mw.moneyObj.increDimes();
            }

            if(userMoney == 25){
                mw.moneyObj.increQuarters();
            }

            if(userMoney == 50){
                mw.moneyObj.increHalfs();
            }

            if(message == null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for your service. Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }


           }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for coming to the Pokemon Distribution Center! \nWe hope you and your " + itemList[itemChoiceNum].getItem() + " catch them all!");
    }


    }
```

Comment: @MattBall When I run it and add money, that is not reflected on money.txt. I'm trying to have it read, store, and update the amounts of coins available.

Comment: There is not a single reference to `PrintWritter` (or other related classes) in your code...

Comment: @SJuan I don't know where to put it. I'll put it back where I had it. I took it out because it wasn't working.

Comment: Why PrintWriter? Why not just use a PrintStream? Any reason for that (they're about the same, but I have no personal experience with PrintWriter) I have used PrintStream an awful lot though.

Comment: I think I can see what you are trying to do. You expect to printwriter to *modify* the data in the file. It does not work that way. You just *overwrite* the file; use the `PrintWriter` methods to write to the file like you would do to console.

Comment: @SJuan76 - I think you're right there. I had similar problems a while back with my own problem. I had to read in the entire file, store it in an ArrayList, then add whatever new content to the end of that arraylist, and shove it all back through a PrintStream. Inefficient as hell, but it worked for me.

Comment: @Singular1ty I'm a beginning Java student, and I haven't learned PrintStream yet. Also my professor is very picky about using things we haven't gone over in class yet.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of what you mean @SJuan76

Comment: @TyGivens I copied down your code, but my compiler is choking on `mw.moneyObj.increQuarters();` and similar. If `mw` is your PrintWriter, I don't think that syntax would work? Not in my Java experience anyway. Furthemore, if you're trying to make `mw` print my calling that function, that definitely won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** I just tested your reading file logic, it does not work. At certain point, you are treating string as int. So it fails. See how I am exacting values from the file:

```
        File moneyFile = null;

        Scanner moneyScan = null;

        int nickels = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int quarters = 0;
        int halfdollars = 0;        

        moneyFile = new File("Money.txt");

        try {
            moneyScan = new Scanner(moneyFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String[] tempAr = new String[2];
        String temp = "";

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            temp = moneyScan.nextLine();
            tempAr = temp.split("//");

            //match nickels
            if(tempAr[1].matches("nickels"))
            {
                nickels = Integer.parseInt(tempAr[0].trim());
                System.out.println(nickels);
            }

            //match dimes
            if(tempAr[1].matches("dimes"))
            {
                dimes = Integer.parseInt(tempAr[0].trim());
                System.out.println(dimes);
            }


            //match quarters
            if(tempAr[1].matches("quarters"))
            {
                quarters = Integer.parseInt(tempAr[0].trim());
                System.out.println(quarters);
            }

            //match halfdollars
            if(tempAr[1].matches("halfdollars"))
            {
                halfdollars = Integer.parseInt(tempAr[0].trim());
                System.out.println(halfdollars);
            }
        }
```

**2)** When you write to your file, it remain blank because you are not flushing and closing the writer stream. Without closing the stream, it won't flush the bytes to file and your file will remain blank.

**ie:** `mw.close();`

Comment: AFAIK PrintWriter auto flushes whenever `printLn` is called. And closing is a formality (I think), rather than something that's mandatory. Also that may be the most complicated way of reading a small text file I can think of - OP said he's only learning still, there's no reason to make him learn how to do splits and matches.

Comment: @Singular1ty, No, you are wrong. It does not. Closing the stream is necessary. Please Google.

Comment: @Singular1ty, He would never be able to write to file unless he closes the stream. Close does two things, flushes the byes and closes the stream.

Comment: My apologies, I looked into that. o_O Been about six months since I last messed around with this. I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: @Singular1ty, I said his reading logic is flawed because his reading logic does not work. I just tested it.

Comment: @Singular1ty, no worries buddy, cheers ! I am perfectly alright with the discussion. :)

Comment: I don't understand most of you anser because as @Singular1ty mentioned, I'm a beginner. I haven't learned most of that. But I do understand that I need a .close.

Comment: @TyGivens, my 1st point mentions that the way you are reading the file is wrong. ie: reading nickels, dimes... values. And it mentions how you should read a file. my 2nd point is quite simple. you need to close the stream. If you don't understand the code then you need to go line by line. Everyone is beginner at 1 point in their life.

Comment: Okay, so I can get it to write to the file, but it's deleting the values that are already in it. Any advice?

Comment: @TyGivens, You don't need old values. Just do calculations(+,- etc) on retrieved values and then write to file in the same sequence the file had.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think your main issue, is that at no point are you actually telling PrintWriter to print anything.

You have `mw.moneyObj.increQuarters();` and similar functions, but they won't do anything by themselves.

The `moneyObj.increQuarters();` is fine, but then you need to call a separate print function elsewhere.

For instance, you might want to have:

```
void printAll(){
    mw.println(moneyObj.getQuarters());
    //Etc for all other printing.

}
```

When the user is finished playing around with the vending machine, ask them to save the results (or intercept the on close function of the JFrame).

Then call `printAll()` and print out to `Money.txt` in the order that you want the figures to appear.

**Edit**
As Ravi mentions below, you will need to call `.close()` at the end of your `printAll()` method to ensure that the printWriter will write to the file properly.

Comment: So added a printAll method, and call it in my driver file. For some reason when I run through everything my money.txt becomes blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TyGivens It shouldn't overwrite the file if all you're doing is PrintLining. Make sure you're only opening the file once. When PrintWriters and PrintStreams open files, they tend to delete the contents. Let me look through some of my old code, as this problem seems familiar.

Comment: @TyGivens no probs, I'm still learning code myself. It helps me that I can help others. :)